# How do I enable CloudWatch logs and metrics on API Gateway using aws-sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Using the AWS web console this is just a matter of navigating to the API's stage in question and ticking the boxes under CloudWatch Settings.
However I am using the aws-sdk to build my API and I seen no way to do this programatically.  There is nothing under createStage, createMethod or anywhere else I have looked.
Can I enable CloudWatch for my API using the aws-sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Java SDK, here's how you could go about it:

1. find the instance of the RestApi for which the stage is meant. For instance by cycling through the result of invoking:

   > RestApi restApi = amazonApiGateway.getRestApis().getItem().get(0)
2. get the stage you wish to configure:

   > Stage stage = restApi.getStageByName("");
3. Create a patch document:

   > PatchDocument patchDocument =
   >       PatchUtils.createPatchDocument(
   >           PatchUtils.createReplaceOperation("/*/*/metrics/enabled", "true"),
   >           PatchUtils.createReplaceOperation("/*/*/logging/dataTrace", "true"),
   >           PatchUtils.createReplaceOperation("/*/*/logging/loglevel", "INFO")
   >       );
   >   stage.updateStage(patchDocument);

Comment: I am using v264 of aws api gateway and I am unable to import PatchDocument, PathUtils classes - is there an updated method to do the above steps

Answer (score 0):

In aws-java-sdk-api-gateway, version: '1.11.264'

I was able to start the CloudWatch Logging using following Code after a lot of time and help from Patrice.

If you are importing a yaml/json formatted swagger to create a API, after Importing is done you get apiID then you deploy it and then you update the Stage Settings as required. So the code below starts from deployment procedure - once deployed then you can change the stage setting

```
private void deployAPI(String name, String apiID) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    CreateDeploymentRequest createDeploymentRequest = new CreateDeploymentRequest();
    createDeploymentRequest.setRestApiId(apiID);
    createDeploymentRequest.setStageName(getEnvironment());
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      try {
        client.createDeployment(createDeploymentRequest);
        break;
      } catch (TooManyRequestsException e) {
        log.error(e);
        sleepToAvoidAWSTooManyRequestException();
      }
    }

    log.info("API deployed  : " + apiID);
    System.out.println("API Stage Updating");
    client.updateStage(new UpdateStageRequest().withRestApiId(apiID).withStageName(getEnvironment())
        .withPatchOperations(getpatchOperations()));
    System.out.println("API Stage Updated");
  }

  private List<PatchOperation> getpatchOperations() {
    List<PatchOperation> list = new ArrayList<PatchOperation>();
    list.add(new PatchOperation().withOp(Op.Replace).withPath("/*/*/metrics/enabled").withValue("true"));
    list.add(new PatchOperation().withOp(Op.Replace).withPath("/*/*/logging/dataTrace").withValue("true"));
    list.add(new PatchOperation().withOp(Op.Replace).withPath("/*/*/logging/loglevel").withValue("ERROR"));
    return list;
  }
```